# Logging in via app when i have a website(php) for the same purpose

Tags: java, android, mysql

Now i have a webpage ../login.php and a database in phpmyadmin as users.
Users contain the password and the usernames of all the registered users. Users can register through website:../register.php.
Now i want to use the login page in my android app and i don't have any idea how to do it.
Basically what i need is:

1. Can i use the webpage interface in my app as a starting activity(MainActivity) and how to do it.
2. If not 1. then how do i check if the username and password match to those saved in phpmyadmin database.
   Please help

Comment: why don't you just make a login screen in android app and log them in using your database credentials?

Comment: how can i connect to the phpmyadmin database and how do i logout the user. In php i can just do session.destroy() to logout how to do it in app

Comment: From review. There is no such thing as phpmyadmin database. It's merely a tool designed to administer `MySQL` database. I believe that users is your actual table, not a database. You may want to look up definition of a table and database.

Comment: Hey, you can take a look at this sample to see how it could be done: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: users is a database and it contains only one table registered_users. I know the difference between a database and a table

Comment: Thanks 0x8BADF00D.It helps

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want first you have to create a .php file that is responsible for getting data by the credentials that users have inputted at your username and password `EditText`. So create a user_login.php like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', 'username', 'password');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$username = $_POST['user']; 
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$query = $handler->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE username = '$username'");
$json = array();
if($query->rowCount() <=0){
    //check if the user exists in the database
    $json = array('reg' =>FALSE);
}else{
    $query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = '$username'");
    while ( $row = $query->fetch()){        
      if ( $row['password'] ===  $pass){
         //check if the submitted password matches the password in your database. You can use any methods to hash your passwords. 
         //This php code implies that you are having the password as plain text in the database which is a sick joke.
         //Check if the user has activated his account
         $json = array('reg' =>TRUE, 'res' =>TRUE, 'activated' =>  $row['activated']);
      }else{
         $json = array('reg' => TRUE, 'res' => FALSE, 'activated' =>  '3');
      }
    }
}

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Then in your Activity in Android App all you have to do is to setup an AsyncTask that will make the connections from and to the database like this:

First add this into your dependencies because HttpClient and NameValuePair are deprecated:

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

Then your java code:

```
private class MyInsertDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            pDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_rate_data_submit));
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", userName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", userPass));
            try {
                httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                Log.e("Responce", result.toString());
                data = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                accountExists = data.getBoolean("reg");
                isRegistered = data.getBoolean("res");
                isActivated = data.getString("activated");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            }
            if (accountExists){
                if(!isRegistered){
                    message = getString("The password is wrong");
                    return false;
                }else {

                    if(isActivated.equals("0")){
                        message = getString("Your account is not yet activated");
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }else {
                message = getString("The username is wrong");
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (aVoid) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                YourActivity.this.finish();
            } else {
              Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

and the global variables :

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
private HttpResponse response;
private HttpClient httpClient;
private HttpPost httpPost;
private HttpEntity httpEntity;
private InputStream is = null;
private MyInsertDataTask task;
private String userName, userPass, result;
private boolean isRegistered = false;
private JSONObject data;
private String isActivated, message;
private boolean accountExists;
```

and finally all you have to do is to create a method that is executing your task and call it from anywhere like this:

```
private void accessWebService() {
        task = new MyInsertDataTask();
        task.execute("http://www.example.com/loginapi/user_login.php");
    }
```

Hope it helps!!!